Python shutil.copytree: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
On GitHub I share an PyInstaller generated exe-File (file1.exe). The idea is an automatized update process if there is a new version of the file. On every start of file1.exe the program checks if there is a new version on GitHub:
response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/...releases/latest")
latestVersion = response.json()["tag_name"]

If latestVersion is newer than the running one a messagebox appears asking if the update should be applied.
My idea is to register an atexit function which runs another python script (updateloader.exe) as a subprocess that downloads the new version from GitHub and copies it into the folder of file1.exe (overwrites file1.exe):
file1:
...
atexit.register(updateloader)
sys.exit()
...
def updateloader():
    subprocess.run("updateloader.exe")

updateloader.exe:
...
shutil.copytree("C:\Users\xy\Downloads\file1.exe", "C:\Users\xy\folder\file1.exe", dirs_exist_ok=True)


What I get is this exception:
('C:\Users\xy\Downloads\file1.exe', 'C:\Users\xy\folder\file1.exe', '[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'). If I close file1.exe manually and run updateloader.exe the copytree is working without an error.
Does anyone has a solution for this problem? Thank you!

Just to make sure: the problem is that when you haven't closed the file, you get an error message that tells you that you weren't allowed to overwrite the file because it's in use? And when you close the file first (so it isn't in use), it is successfully copied? And you are asking what the "solution" is for this "problem"? I don't understand what "problem" you want a "solution" for. The operating system won't allow you to copy over a file that's in use; why is this unexpected? And why should this be considered a programming problem? It's your operating system which imposes this restriction.

Thanks for the quick answer! I thought file1.exe is closed already because of sys.exit() at the moment the atexit function "uploader" is executed but this is not the case obviously. Just to understand it: "uploader" belongs to file1.exe (the same process, even it runs a subprocess), so file1.exe is finally closed AFTER executing "uploader", right?

subprocess.run() waits for the new process to complete which is the source of your issue, file1.exe will be running until after updateloader.exe is finished.

Your code creates a deadlock.
subprocess.run("updateloader.exe")

The file1.exe application is launching a subprocess which is tasked with replacing the parent application. The file1.exe process is waiting to exit while the task is being attempted so the executable is open and cannot be replaced.
To perform the update a detached process that isn't waited on is required. The Microsoft documentation states that the flag for creating a detatched process is 0x00000008.
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

pid = subprocess.Popen(["updateloader.exe"], creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS).pid

Explanation:
The documentation for the subprocess module explains that run() is a convenience function which uses the lower level Popen class under the hood.
The run() function executes the command described by the provided arguments and waits for the command to complete. On completion an instance of subprocess.CompletedProcess is returned. If the subprocess fails a subprocess.CalledProcessError exception is raised.
In your case, run() is creating a subprocess to replace the executable file which is the parent process waiting for the subprocess to complete. The file cannot be overwritten as it is opened for execution and so the operation generates an exception.
By using the lower level Popen class you have greater control, the parent process does not wait for the subprocess to complete before executing the next instruction, sys.exit(), unless you want to do so.
An instance of Popen has a wait() method which can be invoked and will wait for the child process to terminate before continuing execution providing similar behaviour to the run() convenience function.

Thanks Dan, that was it! No error with Popen and DETACHED_PROCESS. Could you explain why it is working with Popen but not with run which also allows to set DETACHED_PROCESS as creationflag?

Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I also read the documentation and was just wondering about the sense of setting a DETACHED_PROCESS flag in the run function if it waits for subprocess completion anyway.

The DETACHED_PROCESS flag allows the subprocess to run without being attached to the parent process, which is useful in specific scenarios like background tasks or services. If you terminate the parent process the subprocess should still run to completion.
